# How to Identify this element using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have tried finding the element by Id, XPath, and CssSelector but have not had any luck.  The test times out while looking for the element.

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="HyperlinkBetaSentry" 
style="top:0px;left:521px;height:24px;width:70px;cursor:pointer;text-align:center" 
class="DashboardHyperlink"><a target="_blank" 
href="https://salsa.sentry.com/SalsaDataSentry/wafForm.aspx?__sso=1234567890" style="color:#e6e7e8;vertical-align:middle;text-decoration:none">Beta Sentry</a></div>
```

I have tried:

```
var title = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#HyperlinkBetaSentry"));
var title = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@id='HyperlinkBetaSentry']"));
var title = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("HyperlinkBetaSentry"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think By.Id should be working. Usually when this happens it's because the code looking for the element is executed before the element exists (e.g. the DOM isn't fully loaded, or some Javascript changed the DOM, or an Ajax request, etc.)

As a test to confirm. Set a break point in your code just before looking for the element. Make sure the element does in fact exist as you expect, then step through the code that tries to find it. Chances are it'll find it.

The only other thing that sometimes causes this is that you're looking into a different frame than where your element is.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues that can cause this.

1. Pass the click to a tag

   var title = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#HyperlinkBetaSentry>a"));
2. Element Load time
3. Duplicate ids

In case 2: You can define some explicit wait for the element to be visible.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("YourID")));
```

See [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for explanation.

In case 3: You might want to use a text base search using xpath or [css with multiple attributes](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-attribute-values/).

```
.//*[.='Beta Sentry']
```